# Opening a cash drawer using C/C++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, c, com, usb

I need to open a cash drawer using C/C++ or Java.  It is a POS-X cash box with a USB connection.  I've never done anything like this before.  I noticed the cash box was linked to the "COM3" port.  I know Java does not have a USB API so I turned to C/C++.

Comment: Do you have the documentation for this cash box?  What does it tell you to do?

Comment: I would use a key.  If the key didn't work, a pry bar and hammer would suffice.

Comment: Hey, that sounds like a fun thing to work on. I have never seen a question like this here either. However, how is anyone suppose to help you without more specifics? I also prefer using a key.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of specifics. My instructor could not provide documentation or a manual of any kind.

Comment: Since its driver creates a virtual COM port for you, you won't need any USB specific code at all. Treat it like a real COM port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forum post about it [here](http://www.pos-x.com/forums/Default.aspx?g=posts&t=138).

In a nutshell, install the driver, change the COM3 baud rate to 9600, and send a "1" to the COM port.

Check out `javax.comm` for a method of communicating with a com port on java.

Comment: Though I cannot seem to find a link to download the Communications API.

Comment: RXTX might be what you need - see http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_is_RXTX.3F

Comment: `COM3` should be accessible from normal file I/O (even from Java) under the name `\\.\COM3`, or sometimes just `COM3` will work. Just open the file for writing, send `"1\r\n"` to it, and it should just open. That does sound like a *high security* cash drawer ;-)

Comment: I'm using C to solve this problem.  I am I am able to create a FILE* reference to the COM3 port, I tried writing the value "1\r\n" to it, but I have been unsuccessful in getting any respose.  What could be the problem?fputs("1/r/n", comport);